# Compare values in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some tables and sql query with join to select from this tables. 
Query result looks like:

```
number|name |value
------------------
1     |name1| 2.48
2     |name1| 1.32
3     |name1| 1.32
```

I need to rewrite this query to add one more field depends of comparison of value field. For example: if it is the first row I need 0, if previous value bigger then I need 1, else 2.

Result I want to have looks like this:

```
number|name |value|status
--------------------------
1     |name1| 2.48|0
2     |name1| 1.32|2
3     |name1| 1.57|1
```

Also I know about case when, but I don't know how I can compare values. The best way, as I see, to iterate through all rows in the result. May be there is some other ways?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(value) over (order by number) is null then 0
             when value > lag(value) over (order by number) then 1
             else 2
        end) as status
from table t;
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery or `outer apply` to do the same thing.

Comment: You need to add `order by` in `Lag` function also it should be `partition by name` and `order by number`.

Comment: @koushikveldanda [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx) and [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx) are both introduced in sqlserver 2012

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using `MSSQL 2012+` then use this.

You need to `left join` with the same table to do this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY name ORDER BY number) Rn,
                *
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT a.*,
       CASE
         WHEN b.rn IS NULL THEN 0
         WHEN a.value < b.value THEN 2
         ELSE 1
       END [Status]
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.Rn = b.Rn + 1
```

or use `Outer Apply`

```
SELECT a.number,a.name,a.value, CASE
             WHEN b.number IS NULL THEN 0
             WHEN a.value < b.value THEN 2
             ELSE 1
           END [Status]
FROM   Yourtable a
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 number,
                                 value
                    FROM   Yourtable  b
                    WHERE  a.name = b.name
                           AND a.number > b.number
                    ORDER  BY number DESC) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Self Join`.

```
SELECT A.number, A.name, A.Value, 

               CASE WHEN A.Value ISNULL THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(A.value, 0) > ISNULL(B.Value, 0) THEN 1 
                    ELSE 2 
                END AS Status 
    FROM Table AS A INNER JOIN Table AS B ON A.number - 1 = B.number
```